# Pivot point/anchor of node (Cytoscape.js)

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am loading a xlsx table with nodes.
The table has the x, y coordinates of the node, the names of the nodes, and something else.
I have a bunch of nodes with x coordinate = 0, but with different y coordinates.
When I load the nodes, because the pivot point of the nodes is in the center, I get this picture

[image: wrongPivot]

I need a picture like this

[image: CorrectPivot]

I did not find any pivot point or anchor for the node in the documentation. If the x coordinate of the node would not work in the center, but along the right edge of the node, everything would be perfect

Comment: you should update node positions accordingly. The positions are based on the center of the node. Your problem stems from varying sizes of nodes. You can put the text as the label of the node and then give the nodes a fixed/same size

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Equal width saves the day and I see this as a good solution to the problem. But still, surely there is no way to change the position from the center of the node to its left border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I solved the problem with this module https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-grid-guide

I just find nodes with the same x coordinate and then call the align fn from module.

It looks something like this

`nodesWithSameXCoord.align(null, "left", nodesWithSameXCoord[0])`